# Where to make mongoose connection / any database connection

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have read several stackoverflow documents and mongoose documentations regarding mongoose.connect() and mongoose.createConnection(), but there does not seem to be a clear explanation on the latter, specifically where to make the connection. I am unsure of where the best place to make mongoose or any database connections are but I usually do them in my server.js file.

Is it okay to make connections in the model itself? When using mongoose.createConnection(), it seems like making the connection in the model is the only option, since if I make a connection using createConnection in server file, I cannot export the connection object that is returned and import it in my model file.

When I use just mongoose.connect() I usually have this set up in my server file,

```
var databaseUri = "mongodb://localhost/sampledatabse1020";

if (process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
} else {
    mongoose.connect(databaseUri)
}

var database = mongoose.connection;

database.on("error", function(err) {
  console.log("Mongoose Error: ", err);
});

database.once("open", function() {
  console.log("Mongoose connection successful.");
});
```

but as I previously stated, if I changed the above code and used

```
var connection = mongoose.createConnection()
```

I cannot export the `connection` variable which hold the connection object returned from mongoose.createConnection(). So would I have to make it in the model it self such as

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/food');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: "First Name is Required"
  },
  last_name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: "Last Name is Required"
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: "Email is Required"
  }
});

var User = connection.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

I also understand another option is to have a separate file to make all database connections rather than in server file, but if I do it this way, how can I do it so that connections are only made when it is necessary?

UPDATE: 
I added the createConnection() inside the model and it seems to be working well. However, I am aware that creating connections inside the model is not ideal, but if that is so, where can I set up the createConnection(), since I can't export it and import it in the models when its defined in another file for example in server.js. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make a mongoose.js file like so:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {useMongoClient: true});

module.exports = {mongoose};
```

Which you then require in your mongoose model files like so:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

That way you only write the connection code once, and are able to import it to wherever you see fit.

Comment: thansk for this. This is very useful.

Comment: @henhen I'm glad, if this answered your question please mark it so others can find it better.

Comment: Sure, although the answer only partially gave me an answer, and I still need to know where to properly use mongoose.createConnection()

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Mongoose, but I think it's a bad idea that every time you create a new model or a instance, a new database connection will be created. There should be only one database connection for each request, and they could be recycled to the pool and wait for the next request. Meaning no matter how many models you have, they should share the same connection to the database. I think connections are still precious with MongoDB. Hope this suggestion will help you a little.

Comment: I am aware of this situation, but the problem with mongoose createConnection() is I am unable to export and import the connection object that is returned inside my model `var connection = mongoose.createConnection('localhost...)`. This is why I set up the connection within the model itself and it seems to be working. Would you happen to have any better solutions?

Comment: Of course you cannot export a local object in a asynchronous callback, but you can put all you logic in the callback, that means, the connection is not created in another file, but in the entry file. Or you can start the pool in another file, but only export the pool object or make it global, so when you need to acquire a connection, you can call pool.getConnection() in anywhere. If you use Express, call getConnection() in a middleware, and call next() in the callback of getConnection().